# unable to open Durandal modal

Tags: knockout.js, modal-dialog, durandal, single-page-application

I am unable to show the durandal model in my application and i am sharing the code below. Please help me on this.

### Model.js

```
    define(['plugins/dialog', 'knockout'], function(dialog, ko) {
        var model = function() {
            this.input = ko.observable('');
        };

        model.prototype.Ok = function () {
            dialog.close(this, this.input());
        };

        model.show = function () {
            return dialog.show(new model());
        };

        return model;
    });
```

### model.html

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Serail No#</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: input" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Ok" data-bind="click: Ok" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

calling method:

define(['./model'],function (demoModel){
 return {
          showmodel:function () {
                      demoModel.show();
                      //app.showDialog('./model');
            }
        };
});
```

i dont find any problem at code. any help is appreciate.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the above code that looks to reference a Durandal modal, or at least where you are correctly implementing a custom modal.  Have you looked at the docs at all yet? http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals/

Comment: i missed out the css class refernce. after adding the durandal css class, model popup is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got output after i do the below changes. Thank you all for your support.

```
define(['./model'],function (demoModel){
 return {
          showmodel:function () {
                      dialog.show(demoModel);
            }
        };
});
```